# Why does there exist a such maximal chain in order topology?

Tags: general-topology, order-topology

Hocking and Young-Topology p.54

Let $X$ be a topological space equipped with an order topology and $x\in X$.

Define $S=\{(a,b): x\in (a,b)\}$ and assume that $S$ is nonempty.

How do I show that there exists a maximal chain $\mathscr{C}$ in $(S,\subset)$ such that $\bigcap \mathscr{C}=\{x\}$?

Comment: Try thinking in the contrapositive.  What would happen if there was a $y\neq x$ such that $y\in \bigcap \mathscr{C}$?  Is that possible?

Comment: @JMoravitz I tried that. Say $x<y$. Since $\mathbb{C}$ is maximal, there is no $z\in \bigcap \mathscr{C}$ such that $z<x$. However, I don't get why this leads contradiction. To lead a contradiction, it should be shown that there is an interval $x\in (z,y)$ such that $(z,y)$ is strictly smaller than every interval in $\mathbb{C}$, but existence of such $y$ does not imply the existence of such $(z,y)$

Comment: Consider $\mathbb{C}=\{(-1/n, 1+1/n)\}$ and $x=0$. Then it is a chain containing $0$ and this seems to be maximal.

Comment: @EricWofsey Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't true.  For instance, let $X=\omega\sqcup \{x\}\sqcup\omega_1^*$, where $\omega_1^*$ denotes $\omega_1$ with the reverse of the normal order, ordered such that for all $n\in\omega$ and $\alpha\in\omega_1^*$, $n<x<\alpha$.  Suppose you have any chain $C$ of open intervals such that $\bigcap C=\{x\}$.  Then for each $n\in\omega$, we can choose an interval $(m_n,\alpha_n)\in C$ for some $m_n\in\omega$ which is larger than $n$ and some $\alpha_n\in\omega_1^*$.  If $(a,b)\in C$ were contained in every $(m_n,\alpha_n)$, then $a$ would have to be greater than every $m_n$, so $a\geq x$, so $x\not\in (a,b)$.  Thus no such $(a,b)$ can exist.  Since $C$ is a chain, this means every element of $C$ contains $(m_n,\alpha_n)$ for some $n$, so $\bigcap C=\bigcap (m_n,\alpha_n)$.  But there exists $\beta\in \omega_1^*$ such that $\beta<\alpha_n$ for all $n$, and then $\beta\in \bigcap (m_n,\alpha_n)$, which is a contradiction.

More generally, this statement will be true if and only if $x$ has an immediate successor, $x$ has an immediate predecessor, or the cofinality of $x$ from the left and the right are equal.